# Tab bar programming

Tags: iphone, tabs

I have a Tab bar based application. Can I change the tabs highlighted Programatically? I mean can i navigate from one tab to the other without actually clicking on the tab icons ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for `UITabBarController`'s `selectedIndex` and `selectedViewController` properties.  [Take a look at the docs](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/selectedIndex).

Comment: I have looked into that class But what I want to do is to navigate from one tab view to another But not using tabs. I have three tabs. And I need to move from tab 1 to tab 2 or tab3 depending on some event on the first tab.